# Error compiling TWebChromium

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle, gmlib

```
 {$IFDEF CHROMIUM}
  TWebChromium = class(TCustomWebChromium)ù
```

at this line I have this error ...

> [dcc32 Warning] GMLib_D_Seattle10.dpk(59): W1033 Unit 'ceflib'
>   implicitly imported into package 'GMLib_D_Seattle10' [dcc32 Error]
>   WebControlVCL.pas(149): E2003 Undeclared identifier:
>   'TCustomWebChromium' [dcc32 Error] WebControlVCL.pas(149): E2021 Class
>   type required

what is wrong ? `$DEFINE CHROMIUM` is activate in `gmlib.inc`

Comment: Is this a typo?: `...Chromium)ù` should it not be `...Chromium);` ?  If you've copied it correctly then obviously you need to change the u-accent-grave to `;`.

Comment: Where did you download the source for CEF?

Comment: Your error tells you what the problem is...it can't find TCustomWebChromium, the unit where ever this is declared needs to be in your path.  Not familiar with this wrapper of Chromium.

Comment: i download dcef3-master,zip from https://github.com/hgourvest/dcef3

Comment: I understand now, wrong version of Chromium, I used the CeF3 while gmlib is based on the CEF. thanks Johan

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the following:

edit gmlib.inc in notepad which is in the component's root folder,

see that for every version of Delphi has a IFDEF

in my case it worked adding ifdef for Delphi 10, add this lines in your gmlib.inc:

```
// Delphi 10 Berlin
{$ IFDEF VER310}
  {$ DEFINE Delphi6}
  {$ DEFINE Delphi7}
  {$ DEFINE DELPHI2005}
  {$ DEFINE Delphi2006}
  {$ DEFINE Delphi2007}
  {$ DEFINE Delphi2009}
  {$ DEFINE DELPHI2010}
  {$ DEFINE DELPHIXE}
  {$ DEFINE DELPHIXE2}
  {$ DEFINE DELPHIXE3}
  {$ DEFINE DELPHIXE4}
  {$ DEFINE DELPHIXE5}
  {$ DEFINE DELPHIXE6}
  {$ DEFINE DELPHIXE7}
  {$ DEFINE DELPHIXE8}
  {$ DEFINE DELPHISE10}
  {$ DEFINE webbrowser}
  {$ IFDEF WIN32}
    {.} $ DEFINE CHROMIUM
    {.} $ DEFINE CHROMIUMFMX
  {$ ENDIF}
{$ ENDIF}
```